# Why is this R computation slower on multiple cores and faster on a single core?

Tags: r, performance, parallel-processing, multicore, slowdown

## Two matrices

```
library(parallel)
m <- matrix(1:12000000000,  nrow=300000)
p <- matrix(21:32, nrow=3)

# Use all pairings of i and j
i_vec <- rep(seq_len(ncol(m)), times = ncol(m))
j_vec <- rep(seq_len(ncol(m)), each = ncol(m))
```

## multicore

```
system.time(mcmapply(i_vec, j_vec, 
   FUN = function(i, j) {
     if (i <= j) return(0)
     sqrt(sum(m[,i]) * sum(m[,j]) * sum(p[,i]) * sum(p[,j]))
   }, mc.cores=7))
```

## single core

```
system.time(mapply(i_vec, j_vec, 
      FUN = function(i, j) {
      if (i <= j) return(0)
      sqrt(sum(as.numeric(m[,i])) * sum(as.numeric(m[,j])) * sum(as.numeric(p[,i])) * sum(as.numeric(p[,j])))
                 }))
```

Running this calculation with seven cores in mcmapply yields

```
  user  system elapsed 
 0.014   0.485   0.019
```

and with 1 core in mapply gives

```
 user  system elapsed 
0.008   0.000   0.008
```

and specifying 1 core for mcmapply gives

```
 user  system elapsed 
0.007   0.000   0.007
```

I can't figure out why this is slower for the multi core than the single core. Is it because the calculation is not very computationally expensive?

Comment: In order to give a meaningful benchmark, you should probably perform the operation 100 times or so. 0.008 seconds is not very far from 0.02.

Comment: OTOH, the multi-core solution spends a lot of time in *system* code (i.e. kernel code; probably due to spawning OS threads), while the single core solutions only spend clock cycles in *user* code (i.e. application code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you parallise code you always get some overhead. With the very simple workload here, the overhead is larger than the workload. If you use a workload that takes some time, e.g. `Sys.sleep(0.1)`, you should see the speedup due to multi-core computation.